# Adding Magento System URL Rewrite

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting, seo

I accidentally deleted some System URL rewrites while attempting to do some 301 redirect magic (i.e. getting one subcategory to direct to another category because they were duplicates but in different parent categories).

After deleting these system URL rewrites I realised that the URLs aren't "pretty" for SEO purposes. For example I deleted a system URL rewrite that was:

`flow-meters`

`/catalog/category/view/s/flow-meters/id/481/`

basically, now every time I click on this category, I get `/catalog/category/view/s/flow-meters/id/481/` whereas I want the URL to say something similar to `sprayers/flow-meters`. Is there a way to add this into Magento via the dashboard? Or do I have to play around with the database tables?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into `core_url_rewrite` table inside the database and manually inserted rows to match the category IDs. Then clearing the cache in `System --> Cache Management` seemed to make the system work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to regenerate Magento's standard URL rewrites by reindexing your system.  Specifically, the Catalog URL index needs rebuilding.

You can do this programmatically via the CLI interface with the following

```
$ php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

Or, per your question, via the backend backend admin application at

```
System -> Index Management
```

Comment: I've tried reindexing the system back end via `System --> Index Management` and it doesn't seem to work, all other categories work fine, however when processing the ones I accidentally deleted before, they don't seem to reindex

Comment: Sounds like you really borked something :)  The next thing I'd check is if your products and categories have URL keys set, and if your system is set to use URLs rewrites in all store views (there's a System -> Configuration variable for that).  Short of that, you're in for a trip to the catalog url rewrite indexer to see why its skipping those URLs.  Good luck!

Comment: URL keys are set, and the URL rewrites are on, by the URL rewrite indexer, did you mean "Catalog --> URL Rewrite Management" ?

Comment: scratch that, I've figured it out, I had to go into the database and manually insert into 'core_url_rewrite`

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of core_url_rewrite table and truncate it. Then clear cache and then reindex the  "Catalog URL Rewrites" from magento Index Management configuration.

Also before reindex  ensure the setting of "Search Engine optimization" in web setting is enabled.

This way I solved my problem.

Hope this will help